Azure DevOps YAML Pipeline - Cache@2 Unable to find package-lock.json file
I'm currently facing an issue with my project setup where the package-lock.json file resides in a subfolder of the project root, for example, subfolder/package-lock.json.
Within my YAML pipeline, I'm executing the Cache@2 task, but it's failing because it can't locate my package-lock.json file, despite the file's existence. (I've confirmed this with a previous step that prints the files in the directory.)
Previously, before some refactoring, the package-lock.json file was located in the project root, and the following step worked with the default path:
parameters:
  - name: npmConfigCache
    type: string
    default: "/home/vsts/.npm"

steps:
  - task: Cache@2
    inputs:
      key: 'npm | "$(Agent.OS)" | package-lock.json'
      restoreKeys: |
        npm | "$(Agent.OS)"
      path: ${{ parameters.npmConfigCache }}
    displayName: Cache npm Packages

Here is how I call the template:
- template: npm/build-and-test.yml@templates
  parameters:
    npmConfigCache: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Subfolder/"

Here is the error:

Has anyone encountered a similar issue before?
I've tried many different approaches

The issue was with the following line:
inputs:
  key: 'npm | "$(Agent.OS)" | package-lock.json'

The subfolder reference needed to be included like below rather than editing the provided path.
inputs:
  key: 'npm | "$(Agent.OS)" | subfolder/package-lock.json'

